# static files not found in django 1.11

Tags: python, django, path, django-staticfiles, static-files

I am getting ["Not Found"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXnJe.jpg) when accessing any page on localhost.
I have read all related posts but still cannot understand why.

I have included `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` in INSTALLED_APPS.

I have `DEBUG = TRUE` in my settings.py

my project layout and code is as the following.

Thank you in advance.

```
repo_root
├── manage.py
│   
├── project_root
│   │
│   ├── accounts
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │   └── urls.py
│   │
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── index.html   
│   │
│   └── static
│       └── assets
│           ├── bootstrap
│           ├── css
│           ├── fonts
│           ├── img
│           └── js
│   
├── config_root
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
│
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(
        BASE_DIR,
        'project_root/static/assets')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(
    BASE_DIR,
    'project_root/staticfiles')
```

index.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>index</title>
    <meta name="description" content="sample_content">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="'static/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,400i,700,700i,600,600i">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="'static/assets/fonts/simple-line-icons.min.css'">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.10.0/baguetteBox.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="'static/assets/css/smoothproducts.css'">
</head>
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^index/$', IndexView.as_view())
```

views.py

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have,

`{% load static %}`

and

`href="{% static 'assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"`

adding these solved the problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Great that you solved it. Accepting an answer or upvote it would be nice, if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your STATICFILES_DIRS isn't defined properly. Your BASE_DIR is most probably defined as your project_root folder, since this is the default Django setting. You should leave out project_root in your definition.

`STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(
        BASE_DIR,
        '/static/')
]`

You should also include static files urls to your urlpatterns.

Check Django docs for further info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

Comment: I have tried changing the STATICFILES_DIRS as suggested, but then I become unable to find any static files when running `python manage.py findstatic`.

Comment: `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`